# Schubert calculus on Grassmannians

Tags: algebraic-geometry, book-recommendation, grassmannian, schubert-calculus

Can anyone please suggest me some notes or books where I can read about Schubert calculus? I am studying Grassmannian varieties so I would like to understand how to use this tool, in particular with Grassmannians.

Comment: There're some discussions in Griffiths and Harris's Principle of Algebraic Geometry

Comment: @JohnMa Thank you for the advice. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book *3264 and all that* is an excellent introduction. I don't know if it's finished, but draft notes were available for free online for a while.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I hope I will find what I am looking for, have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

Another excellent source is the following article by Kleiman and Laksov: ["Schubert calculus"](http://www.mccme.ru/~valya/Kleiman%20Laksov%20Schubert%20calculus.pdf).

For reference, it is published in American Mathematical Monthly, vol 79, no 10 (dec 1972).

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will have a look at that too. Have a nice day.